# redirect sub folder installation to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i am trying to redirect sub folder installation to root

ie. http://mydomain/auth/login its actually http://mydomain/test/web/index.php/auth/login

works fine with all urls

but not working if i am trying to access http://mydomain getting **403 Forbidden error**

**note**

- http://mydomain/index.php to http://mydomain/test/web/index.php is working
- http://mydomain to http://mydomain/test/web/index.php is not working

i am looking to access http://mydomain without Forbidden error and /index.php in url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should exclude any URI start with `/test/web/index.php` at your code , so t should look like this :

```
  Options -Indexes
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/web/index.php
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
```

Then , you could handle error request that passes a rule above .

**Moreover** , `Options -Indexes` , in short ,means prevent directory listing when there is no index page at that directory , your code should look like this :

```
   DirectoryIndex /test/web/index.php
   Options -Indexes
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/web/index.php
   RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,NE]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/web/index.php
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: @GaneshKandu do you have index page in root directory? paste the rest of .htaccess file

Comment: i have index.php in test/web folder not in webroot directory and .htaccess in webroot directory

Comment: @GaneshKandu that why this error happened , you should add index otherwise , error will happened unless you change directory index

Comment: i want to load mydomain.com/test/web/index.php on access of mydomain.com url
don't want to access index of my root directory

Comment: @GaneshKandu ok now understand , let me change my code

Comment: @GaneshKandu test last code with update and let me know